# Is Brezis' theorem 8.2 necessary for remark 11?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $I=(a, b)$ be an open interval in $\mathbb R$. I would like to verify *Remark 11* at page 214 in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*

> Let $I$ be bounded and $p,q \in [1, \infty]$. By **Theorems 8.2** and **8.8**,
> $$
> [u] := \|u'\|_p + \|u\|_q
> $$
> is an equivalent norm of $W^{1, p} (I)$.

In below attempt, I don't use **Theorems 8.2**. There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt. Could you please have a check on it?

---

We have $\|u\|_{W^{1,p}} := \|u'\|_p + \|u\|_p$. By **Theorem 8.8** in the same book, there exists a constant $C_1$ (depending only on $|I|$) such that
$$
\|u\|_{\infty} \leq C_1\|u\|_{W^{1, p}} \quad \forall u \in W^{1, p}(I).
$$

1. We consider the case $1 \le p \le q \le \infty$. By interpolation inequality, there exist constant $C_2$ (depending only on  $p,q,|I|$) such that for all $u \in W^{1, p}(I)$ we have
   $$
   \|u\|_p \le C_2 \|u\|_q
   \quad \text{and} \quad
   \|u\|_q \le \|u\|_p^{p/q} \|u\|_\infty^{(q-p)/q}.
   $$

Then for all $u \in W^{1, p}(I)$ we have
$$
\begin{align*}
 \|u\|_q &\le \|u\|_p^{p/q} (C_1\|u\|_{W^{1, p}})^{(q-p)/q} \\
 & \le C_1^{(q-p)/q} \|u\|_{W^{1,p}},
 \end{align*}
$$
and thus
$$
[u] \le (1+C_1^{(q-p)/q}) \|u\|_{W^{1,p}}.
$$

On the other hand,
$$
\begin{align*}
\|u\|_{W^{1,p}} &\le \|u'\|_p + C_2 \|u\|_q \\
&\le (1+C_2) [u].
 \end{align*}
$$

1. We consider the case $1 \le q < p \le \infty$. By interpolation inequality, there exist constant $C_3$ (depending only on  $p,q,|I|$) such that for all $u \in W^{1, p}(I)$ we have
   $$
   \|u\|_q \le C_2 \|u\|_p
   \quad \text{and} \quad
   \|u\|_p \le \|u\|_q^{q/p} \|u\|_\infty^{(p-q)/p}.
   $$

We precede as previously and complete the proof.